# Clean way to "require" in nodejs when having to pass params

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got files called socket.js and Chat.js.

Let's say Chat.js contains:

```
function Chat(io, socket) {
  this.sendChatMessage(data) {};
}
module.exports = Chat;
```

And socket.js

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      var Chat = new (require('./Chat'))(io, socket),
    });
}
```

After several tries, the above is the cleanliest way of requiring "Chat" that I've found, but it still looks weird for something so frequently used.

I tried stuff like (still clean I guess)

```
var Chat = require('./Chat'),
    Chat = new Chat(io, socket);
```

Also tried adding the "new" in module.exports = new Chat; directly etc. etc.

Is there any standard for this? If not, what do you use?

Comment: `Chat = new Chat(io, socket);` should be `chat = new Chat(io, socket);` constructors uppercase, instances lowercase.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just requiring at the top? `var Chat = require('./Chat');` I'm not one to waste time trying to save a few characters, especially when the *slightly* more verbose version is actually easier to look at and grok immediately.

Comment: @jSmith can you confirm that Chat.js code is correct? You execute `this.sendChatMessage` inside constructor with `data` variable which is undefined. Please clarify and then I can provide you some with examples.

Comment: @JanŚwięcki  later on in my code I call chat.sendChatMessage(data) with data having content.

Comment: Yeah @Chev, I think the 2-lines version is good as well. I actually ended up using JMM's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's how you do it: export whatever function(s) you need and call them after requiring the module.

> Also tried adding the "new" in module.exports = new Chat

Don't do that unless you really want to export an instance and not the constructor.

It's pretty common to use a pattern like this so you could omit the `new` where you call the constructor:

```js
function Chat(io, socket) {
  if (! (this instanceof Chat)) return new Chat(io, socket);
  this.sendChatMessage(data) {};
}
```

```js
var Chat = require('./Chat')(io, socket)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is most popular now but here is how I might do it with babel and the ES6 standard:

```
// chat.js                                                

export default class Chat {                               
  constructor(io, socket) {                               
    this.io = io;                                         
    this.socket = socket;
    this.sendMessage(data);                                
  }                                                       

  sendMessage(data) {                                     
    //                                                    
  }                                                       
}                                                         

// iochat.js                                              

import Chat from './chat';                                

export default function connectChat (io) {                
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {                       
    let chat = new Chat(io, socket);                      
  });                                                     
}                                                         


// tio.js                                                 

import connectChat from './iochat';                       

let io = { on:()=>{}};                                    
connectChat(io);
```

Although I am guessing the connectChat thing is part of a larger module or app.